# A question regardig anaphoric reference to time

Tags: writing-style, anaphora

I have a simple question regarding anaphoric reference to time.

ex) How is the weather in New York next Monday?

and for the next sentence I want to make an anaphoric reference to Monday.

say the next sentence was:

(assuming weather is good) Remind me to make an appointment with my doctor on Monday.

In this sentence, what would be an appropriate anapahora for Monday?

Comment: "If I could save time in a bottle ..."  Oops!!  That's an *amphora*!

Comment: It's unclear. Could be *remind me*, could be *make an appointment*, could be *with my doctor*. Remind me next Monday - maybe - make the appointment on Monday - more likely - but most likely it means I want to see the doc on Monday. So the reference is to a Monday *appointment*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a referential pronoun to replace the second use of Monday. For circumstances of time, English is fairly limited, having only two demonstrative adverbs for time (*now* and *then*) so the sentence could be:

"Remind me to make an appointment with my doctor then"

and the listener can resolve the meaning *then* to be *on Monday*.

Otherwise, English makes use of other demonstrative words to make time reference, with phrases such as *at that time* or *on that day*. 
Strictly speaking, the second mention of *Monday* implicitly makes anaphoric reference to the first mention of *Monday*. Explicit marking of the anaphoric relationship is not necessary, especially when replacing the word *Monday* with *then* would make the sentence less clear, and making the connection more explicit with *that Monday* would make the sentence more unwieldy.

---

Source: 
Halliday, M. A. K., & Hasan, R. (2014). *Cohesion in english*. Routledge.

Comment: Thank you so much